# HttpURLConnection working on Android 6.X (Elephone P9000) but not on Android 4.X (Samsung G S3)

Tags: android, httprequest, httpurlconnection

With the exact same code an HTTURLConnection is not working on my Samsung Galaxy S3(v4.x), but it does on on my Elephone P9000 (v6.x).

On the Galaxy I get a 400 response code.

Here is my snippet. Help will be greatly appreciated.

```
class Request extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Response> {

    private Exception exception;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    protected Response doInBackground(Void... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(API_URL + "email=" +URLEncoder.encode(Email, "utf-8") + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(Password, "utf-8"));                
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            Log.d("Response Code: ", String.valueOf(urlConnection.getResponseCode()));
            Log.d("Error Body: ", String.valueOf(urlConnection.getErrorStream()));
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();

                //Parse Response
                Log.d("Response", stringBuilder.toString());
                JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(stringBuilder.toString()).nextValue();
                Response res = new Response();

                res.setStatus(object.getString("status"));
                res.setUserID(object.getString("UserID"));
                res.setError(object.getString("error"));

                Log.d("Req Response obj Status",res.getStatus() );


                return res;
            }
            finally{
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Check your server logs to see if you see anything of note that explains why your server is rejecting the request.

Comment: What does 400 mean?

Comment: `stringBuilder.toString()`. What do you get there?

Comment: 400 is "Bad Request". Definitely check your server logs and do `Log.d("URL: " + url);` Also add your log messages to your question so we can see where it went wrong.